# Frequency of vibration from potential field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy, oscillators

I have an equation:
$$V = 200x^2 + 150 ergs/gm$$
How can I get the frequency of its vibration? (I have the mass of object which is 4gm)
I don't know where to start to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate with respect to displacement. You would get an electric field with a negative sign, $(-400x)$. So you would get that force varies with displacement $(F=-kx)$. Hence it would execute simple harmonic motions, and its time period can be obtained via the equation $2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$.